# Python folder names in the directory

Tags: python

how can i get the folder names existing in a directory using Python ?

I want to save all the subfolders into a list to work with the names after that but i dont know how to read the subfolder names ?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os

directory_list = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/your/dir", topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        directory_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))

print directory_list
```

**EDIT**

If you only want the first level and not actually "walk" through the subdirectories, it is even less code:

```
import os

root, dirs, files = os.walk("/path/to/your/dir").next()
print dirs
```

This is not really what `os.walk` is made for. If you really only want one level of subdirectories, you can also use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) like Yannik Ammann suggested:

```
root='/path/to/my/dir'
dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
print dirlist
```

Comment: thanks . But this code is just listing the names, however i cannot save them into an array or list ?

Comment: Sure you can... I've edited my answer, so it appends the entries to a list.

Comment: ahh really cool feature, there is still one problem, i am getting all the time the complete tree of all subdirectories in the path, i just need the first structure: C:\MyPath and in this folder i have folder1,folder2,folder3....
and i just need the folder1,folder2 etc names and not the subfolders of folder1.....

Comment: I've edited my answer again, regarding to your new condition.

Comment: Does this not work for python 3.x? I am getting `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: `dir_lst = [os.path.join(root, name) for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/your/dir", topdown=False) for name in dirs ]`

Comment: @ashley With Python 3, `next` changed to `__next__`.

Answer (score 16):

Starting with Python 3.4, you can also use the new [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('some/folder')
subdirectories = [x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]

print(subdirectories)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `os.listdir()` [here a link to the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

*Warning returns files and directories*

example:

```
import os

path = 'pyth/to/dir/'
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
```

**update:** you need to check if the returned names are directories or files

```
import os

path = 'pyth/to/dir/'
# list of all content in a directory, filtered so only directories are returned
dir_list = [directory for directory in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(path+directory)]
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` lists also files, not only directories.

Comment: it does? why would it be called listdir if it gives back files?? 

Comment: Because it lists the content of a directory :)

Answer (score 8):

You should import os first.

```
import os
files=[]
files = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir(FileDirectoryPath))]
```

This would give you **list with all files in the FileDirectoryPath sorted**.

Answer (score 6):

I use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)

**Get all folder names of a directory**

```
folder_names = []
for entry_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    entry_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, entry_name)
    if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        folder_names.append(entry_name)
```

**Get all folder paths of a directory**

```
folder_paths = []
for entry_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    entry_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, entry_name)
    if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        folder_paths.append(entry_path)
```

**Get all file names of a directory**

```
file_names = []
for file_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    file_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_names.append(file_name)
```

**Get all file paths of a directory**

```
file_paths = []
for file_name in os.listdir(MYDIR):
    file_path = os.path.join(MYDIR, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        file_paths.append(file_path)
```

Comment: For the "with path" versions, this is shorter: `[_ for _ in glob.glob(os.path.join(MYDIR, '*')) if os.path.isdir(_)]`, at the expense of importing `glob`.

Answer (score 5):

For python 3 I'm using this script

```python
import os

root='./'
dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
for dir in dirlist:
        print(dir)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `os.walk(path)`

```
import os

path = 'C:\\'

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    for directory in directories:
        print os.path.join(root, directory)
```

Comment: please how i am able to print only 2 down levels (sub directories) of directories...

Comment: import os

path = 'C:\\'

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    if root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep) <= 2:
        print root

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x: If you want only the directories in a given directory, try:

```
import os
search_path = '.'   # set your path here.
root, dirs, files = next(os.walk(search_path), ([],[],[]))
print(dirs)
```

The above example will print out a list of the directories in the current directory like this:

```
['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3']
```

The output contains only the sub-directory names.

If the directory does not have sub-directories, it will print:

```
[]
```

**os.walk()** is a generator method, so use **next()** to only call it once. The 3-tuple of empty strings is for the error condition when the directory does not contain any sub-directories because the os.walk() generator returns 3-tuples for each layer in the directory tree. Without those, if the directory is empty, next() will raise a StopIteration exception.

For a more compact version:

```
dirs = next(os.walk(search_path), ([],[],[]))[1]
```